# Windows DNS doesn't resolve local records to different subnet without domain suffix

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a domain with a windows DNS that works great for every computer in that subnet. Today I setup a remote office and joined them to the network through a VPN tunnel and so those computers are on another subnet. I then set the remote office to use the main office DNS and it works great for almost everything.

My only problem is that i cannot query for servers in the main office without having to add the full domain suffix;

nslookup dcserver.example.com <-- Works

nslookup dcserver <-- Doesn't work

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the remote office part of the same domain as the main office?

Comment: It's no joined to a domain yet. Eventually it will be joined to the same domain but i would prefer it to work before that

Comment: Well in that case you'll need to go with JamesRyan's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add them to the main domain or add the suffix in DNS settings.  connection properties > TCP/IP properties > advanced > dns > append these dns suffixes  (you can also set this via dhcp)

Comment: While this would work I was hoping for a solution in the DNS server without having to join the machines to the domain

Comment: @Secana You need to set the search suffix on the client one way or another - setting it in the connection properties doesn't require a domain join.  Do you use a DHCP server?  You can set the search suffix there as well.

Comment: @ShaneMadden +1, you should add that as an answer in its own right.

Comment: you can set most of those options using dhcp